# Problem in adding Image Icon to combined charts in Java Swing GUI

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, charts

I created 2 graphs and displayed them in one frame. Now I want to add Image Icon. However there is a problem with frame. I know that I have not been used any frame. However is there any way to add image without JFrame variable or How can I modify my code using JFrame. It must show 2 graphs in one window

My versions: *xchart 3.8.7*

```
           *jfreechart 1-0.19*

           *jserialcomm- 1.0.23*
```

Here is the error:`Cannot resolve symbol frame`

```
import org.knowm.xchart.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Frame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create instances of your plotter classes
        SerialPlotter plotter1 = new SerialPlotter();
        SerialPlotterForSensor2 plotter2 = new SerialPlotterForSensor2();

        // Get the charts from your plotters
        XYChart chart1 = plotter1.getChart();
        XYChart chart2 = plotter2.getChart();

        // Set the same title for both charts
        chart1.setTitle("Sensor 1");
        chart2.setTitle("Sensor 2");

        // Create a list of charts
        List<XYChart> charts = new ArrayList<>();
        charts.add(chart1);
        charts.add(chart2);

        // Display the list of charts in a matrix layout using the SwingWrapper class
        SwingWrapper<XYChart> sw = new SwingWrapper<>(charts);
        sw.displayChartMatrix();
        ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("img.png");
        frame.setIconImage(image.getImage());//Error apperas here
        // Create a timer to repaint the chart every second
        Timer timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                sw.repaintChart();
            }
        });
        timer.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Should probably be `sw.displayChart().setIconImage(image.getImage());`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show two graphs in one window and if there's a problem with the frame you can just add the JFrame in your SwingWrapper class in which you are calling the method `displayChartMatrix()`

Instead of:-

```
SwingWrapper<XYChart> sw = new SwingWrapper<>(charts);
sw.displayChartMatrix();
```

Try this:-

```
SwingWrapper<XYChart> sw = new SwingWrapper<>(charts);
JFrame frame = sw.displayChartMatrix();
```

where we are creating a JFrame variable

also include these lines at the beginning of the code:-

```
import org.knowm.xchart.XYChart;
import org.knowm.xchart.SwingWrapper;
```

Comment: It didn't fix the problem. Code is error free. However, Nothing has changed in the windows